# I have a dojo tabcontainer that has two tabs, each tab (ie contentPane) has a title, how do I make the title bold?

Tags: dojo, tabs, title, tabcontainer

I have a Dojo TabContainer that has two tabs, each tab (ie ContentPane) has a title, how do I make the title bold?

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways of doing it:

- Inline it; ex: `<div dojoType="dijit.ContentPane" title="<span style='font-weight:bold'>my title</span>"></div>`
- Change CSS `.tabLabel { font-weight: bold }`
- If no access to CSS, query that individual element and replace it with dojo.style()